# How to get JSON data from foursquare venue tips api url and make it in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, json, foursquare

I am new to php and json.
My goal is here to get specific venue tips from foursquare api and display them as HTML content.
I can get tips that i wanted as json however i have problems to decode them and display them as HTML

Here what i tried;

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/53a03c0a498ebaba35742592/tips?sort=recent&oauth_token=TOKEN_HERE');

$data = json_decode($json,true);

$Geonames = $data['items'][0];

echo "<pre>";

print_r($Geonames);

exit;
```

I did not get anything. Then i tried another way to get them. I could get response from foursqure i could get tips but i cannot decode them. I just need `text`, `canonicalUrl`, `firstname`, `lastname` and `photo` data from api response.

Need your helps can`t wait to see them.
Thanks

Comment: Start debugging. `var_dump($json)` to confirm that you actually received something useful from foursquare, then `var_dump($data)` to see what it decoded to. You should have done BOTH of these before ever coming here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the structure of decoded data first. You receive complex array where items are in respons and then tips. So if you want to get them, you have to call to

```
$data['response']['tips']['items'][0]
```

Use print_r() or var_dump() on received data first and analyze the structure before you ask again.

Comment: All figured out. Learned something you by your help. Thanks.